# How to add comparison bars to a plot to denote which comparison a p value corresponds to

Tags: r, ggplot2, comparison, ggpubr

I'm using the following data frame:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Genotype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L,2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
.Label= c("miR-15/16 FL", "miR-15/16 cKO"), class = "factor"), 
Tissue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("iLN", "Spleen", "Skin", "Colon"), class = "factor"), 
`Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,, CD4+/Foxp3+,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127` = c(518L, 
715L, 572L, 599L, 614L, 881L, 743L, 722L, 779L, 843L, 494L, 
610L, 613L, 624L, 631L, 925L, 880L, 932L, 876L, 926L, 1786L, 
2079L, 2199L, 2345L, 2360L, 2408L, 2509L, 3129L, 3263L, 3714L, 
917L, NA, 1066L, 1059L, 939L, 1269L, 1047L, 974L, 1048L, 
1084L)),
.Names = c("Genotype", "Tissue", "Cells/SC/Live/CD8—,,CD4+/Foxp3+,Median,<BV421-A>,CD127"),
row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and trying to make a plot using ggplot2 where box plots and points are displayed grouped by "Tissue" and interleaved by "Genotype". The significance values are displaying properly but I would like to add lines to denote the comparisons being made and have them start at the center of each "miR-15/16 FL" box plot and end at the center of each "miR-15/16 cKO" box plot and sit directly below the significance values. Below is the code I am using to generate the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
color.groups <- c("black","red")
names(color.groups) <- unique(df1$Genotype)
shape.groups <- c(16, 1)
names(shape.groups) <- unique(df1$Genotype)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Tissue, y = df1[3], color = Genotype, shape = Genotype)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(), outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  ylim(0,1.2*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE)) +
  ylab('MFI CD127 (of CD4+ Foxp3+ T cells') +
  scale_color_manual(values=color.groups) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shape.groups) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.title.x=element_blank(), aspect.ratio = 1,
                     text = element_text(size = 9)) +
  stat_compare_means(show.legend = FALSE, label = 'p.format', method = 't.test',
                     label.y = c(0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(1:10),], na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(11:20),], na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(21:30),], na.rm = TRUE),
                                 0.1*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE) + max(df1[3][c(31:40),], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created the brackets with three calls to `geom_segment`. These calls use a new `dmax` data frame created to provide the reference y-values for positioning the brackets and the p-value labels. The values `e` and `r` are for tweaking these positions.

I've made a few other changes to your code.

1. Change the name of the third column to `temp` and use this name `y=temp` in the call to ggplot. Your original code uses `y=df1[3]`, which essentially reaches outside the plot environment to the `df1` object in the parent environment, which can cause problems. Also, having a short name to refer to makes it easier to generate the `dmax` data frame and refer to its columns.
2. Use the `dmax` data frame for `label.y` positions in `stat_compare_means`, which reduces the amount of code needed. (Incidently, `stat_compare_means` seems to require hard-coded `label.y` positions, rather than getting them from an `aes` mapping of the data.)
3. Position the p-value labels an absolute distance above each pair of box plots (using the value `e`), rather than a multiplicative distance. This makes it easier to keep spacing consistent between p-value labels, brackets, and box plots.

---

```
# Use a short column name for the third column
names(df1)[3] = "temp"

# Generate data frame of reference y-values for p-value labels and bracket positions
dmax = df1 %>% group_by(Tissue) %>% 
  summarise(temp=max(temp, na.rm=TRUE),
            Genotype=NA)

# For tweaking position of brackets
e = 350
r = 0.6
w = 0.19
bcol = "grey30"

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Tissue, y = temp, color = Genotype, shape = Genotype)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(), outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  ylim(0,1.2*max(df1[3], na.rm = TRUE)) +
  ylab('MFI CD127 (of CD4+ Foxp3+ T cells') +
  scale_color_manual(values=color.groups) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shape.groups) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.title.x=element_blank(), aspect.ratio = 1,
                     text = element_text(size = 9)) +
  stat_compare_means(show.legend = FALSE, label = 'p.format', method = 't.test',
                     label.y = e + dmax$temp) +
  geom_segment(data=dmax,
               aes(x=as.numeric(Tissue)-w, xend=as.numeric(Tissue)+w, 
                   y=temp + r*e, yend=temp + r*e), size=0.3, color=bcol, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data=dmax,
               aes(x=as.numeric(Tissue) + w, xend=as.numeric(Tissue) + w, 
                   y=temp + r*e, yend=temp + r*e - 60), size=0.3, color=bcol, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_segment(data=dmax,
               aes(x=as.numeric(Tissue) - w, xend=as.numeric(Tissue) - w, 
                   y=temp + r*e, yend=temp + r*e - 60), size=0.3, color=bcol, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]

To address your comment, here's an example to show that the method above inherently adjusts to any number of x-categories.

Let's begin by adding two new tissue categories:

```
library(forcats)

df1$Tissue = fct_expand(df1$Tissue, "Tissue 5", "Tissue 6")
df1$Tissue[seq(1,20,4)] = "Tissue 5"
df1$Tissue[seq(21,40,4)] = "Tissue 6"

dmax = df1 %>% group_by(Tissue) %>% 
  summarise(temp=max(temp, na.rm=TRUE),
            Genotype=NA)
```

Now run exactly the same plot code listed above to get the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Cool! Yeah that works quite well. It would be better if the ends of the brackets aligned with the center of the box plots...probably just need to adjust the 0.45 value...Where did you get 0.45 value? I had been hoping for a way to do this with ggpubr that would allow it to be more accommodating to adding additional tissues or removing tissues from the plot. They have a "comparisons =" call that you can pass a list of comparisons to but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: The x categories are positioned numerically at x-values 1 through n, where n=4 in this case. So, +/- 0.45 will leave a little bit of space between brackets for adjacent groups (as you can see in the first two groups in the plot, as they have similar y positions). I've updated the code by adding a `w` parameter to set the bracket width. This method automatically adjusts for different numbers of x-categories, since `w` is always added/subtracted from whatever number of x-categories the plot happens to have.